# Accepting float values from a file in c

Tags: c, file

I am designing a Cash register in which the aim of the program is to calculate the change that has to be returned to the customer.

The Input of the program is given in form of a file from command line argument.The input file contains several lines. Each line is one test case. Each line contains two numbers which are separated by a semicolon. The first is the Purchase price (PP) and the second is the cash(CH) given by the customer.

eg.

15.94;16.00

17;16

I read the values from the input file character by character and then i am using atof function for conversion after accepting the input in form of a string.Is there a better and efficient way to accept the input???

Comment: Unless you are designing a Cash register for amounts expressed in a base that is a power of two, using a binary floating-point representation is not a good idea.

Comment: Float (or double) values don't work. Better represent all money values as integers in cents (might need `long long int`...), so you don't run into problems with rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fscanf.html) instead.

Comment: i have read about fscanf but how to use it for comma separated values?

Comment: @poorvank, you seem to have semicolon separated values... Do check the documentation and examples provided at the link, but the format `%f;%f` is likely what you're looking for.